# Sim 900 GPRS shield pinout

Tags: arduino, gsm

I'm currently working on a project involving a GPRS Shield based on Sim 900 Chip

I was wondering if anyone would know which ones are the VIN Pin and the RING pin ? 
It doesn't say on the board itself and all other searches have lead me to a dead end.

Also if you have a detailed pin layout it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

The GPRS shield is the one in the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzMnA.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ring Pin

If you have a Multimeter with continuity testing, check where the RI pin (#4) on the Sim 900 chip is broken out to. Here is an overview of the pins:
[image]

If it isn't (some shields don't have them broken out) you could solder a wire to the RI pin with an LED and resistor to Ground, something like this:

[RI Pin]--------[wire]--------[LED]--------[Resistor (330Ohms?)]--------[Ground]

The ring indicator is HIGH by default and LOW when there is an incoming call. So, when there is no call the LED is on and off when there is an incoming call.

---

### VIN

When the position of the switch (middle left in the image below) is set to "extern" (right), you have to supply power to the barrel connector. When you set the switch to the left position, the module takes power from the 5V pin of the arduino OR (dont attach both!) an external power supply you attach to that pin.

[image]

Hope it helps :)

PS: These SIM modules can have current peaks up to 2 Amps. I recommend you to use an external power source that can provide minimum 2A at 5V.

### Edit:

This might be helpful: 
http://wiki.seeed.cc/GPRS_Shield_v1.0/. I think its the same module as yours. Have a look at the "GPRS Shield v1.4 Schematic" at the bottom of the page.

### Edit 2:

Comparing the board from the link and yours, i'm very certain that the ring pin is the one marked in red in the image above. Checking with a multimeter doesnt hurt though. You can add the same circuit i described above to that pin to add an LED indicator.

Comment: Wow this is a huuge help. Also although I have supplied external power at 5V 2A, it also works at 9V as well. Both of the voltages were applied to the barrel connector.  I believe it should work with 9V on that VIN pin as well right? It should go through the same power regulator. Is that correct?

Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have no idea why they didn't bother to write the pinouts on the shield itself, it would have been much easier.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me. Now I dare ask you another question.
Would you know if it would be possible to boost the speaker signal without any other external attached components? Like software boost or something? 
Somewhere around 50% would be great. Thank you

Comment: If your module is connected to an Arduino over UART (Rx,Tx Serial), you can set the volume by sending the `AT+CLVL` command. `AT+CLVL?` returns the currently set volume [%]. Ex: if you want to set the volume to 70%, send `AT+CLVL=70`

Comment: After every successful command the module will append an **OK** to the command you have sent. So  `AT+CLVL=70` should return  `AT+CLVL=70  OK`

Comment: Have a look at the SIM900 AT Command manual for more commands like sending SMS, low power modes, etc. [https://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf](https://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf) **Page 90**

Comment: except for connecting different pins the command should be the same right? I mean for connecting. Like mySerial.println("ATDxxxxxxxxx;");

Comment: Yes they are. Just have to make sure the correct pins are defined for `mySerial`

Comment: pins defined on the arduino board i believe. I do have a connector to solder to the uart pins but it seems that the ring pin is missing so i have to use the multimeter to find the other termination

Comment: one more question, 
If connecting via UART, should I switch the jumpers to hardware serial? Or just leave them be as they are now on software serial?

if connecting via software serial instead of the UART
Shouldn't the volume be 100% because I believe if I try the AT+CVL=100 command the sound level would be the same. 

Thank you

Comment: Use software serial (pin 7 = Rx, pin 8 = Tx). I'm not quite sure if i understand the last question but the `AT+CLVL` command doesn't depend  on the type of serial connection you are making

Comment: I meant if i have to move the jumper from the gsm shield to hardware rx tx instead of software

Comment: No, leave the jumper on software. Is your shield stacked on your arduino or is it separate ?

Comment: I seem to be a bit lost, i've tried AT+CLVL=90 and tried to call right after but no result. Do you have a complete command? thank you
Shield is eparate. I can call via UART but the AT+CLVL gives me problems momentarily

Comment: I seemed to got it working

I need to write down 2 separate at commands with a 2 sec delay between them. It doesnt seem to work all in the same line

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. Are you able to adjust the volume with `AT+CLVL` ?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to be sticky as well. I mean that once I set a volume level, even if I turn off the shield and power it back on the volume is the same. Second time I'm not using level control and the volume is the same. Unfortunately even at 100% would still need some boosting. But I can work with that.

The shield is separate. I'm using 3 wires, TX, RX and GND